# Can I charge my MacBook Pro 2015 without using MagSafe 2 power port?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, magsafe

I have a MacBook Pro [(Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)](https://www.apple.com/in/macbook-pro/specs-2015/). Now after three years of use, the charger isn't responding to being plugged in. I tried to reset the SMC by holding down the left side shift control option and the power key but no luck.

Is it possible to charge my MacBook using Thunderbolt 2 ports or USB 3 ports? I have seen some videos on Youtube people charging their device using these but I am not sure.

Comment: Could you link to those videos?

Answer (score 2):

It is neither possible nor advisable to charge your MacBook Pro using Thunderbolt or USB ports.

It is possible that either your MagSafe 2 port or the charging adapter is damaged. Please stop plugging in the charger if you spot burnt marks on either one of them. It’s recommended that you get your MacBook Pro inspected by an authorized Apple technician. You may be eligible for free service and replacement if you are covered under AppleCare.

Comment: If it is not possible there is no need to advise anything? Do you mean not advisable "to try"? (I'd still like to see those videos, though. Prank?) –– The point "after three years" from OP should warrant that you rephrase that to "You may still be eligible…" (either because the three years are not really up completely or they display some generosity…)

Answer (score 2):

I know, it is a late answer, but it might be still of relevance. I still use a MacBook Pro Mid 2015. Nowadays, there are USB-C to Magsafe 2 adapters. Just search for it on Internet. I replaced my old Magsafe 2 charger (60W) with such an adapter and a 65 W USB-C Charger.

My old charger was still functioning, but it was really great to get rid of it, because it was bulky and only worked for the Macbook. A USB-C charger can charge a lot of different devices, and also older devices with some adapters. [image]