# Can I charge a MacBook Air using the Thunderbolt 1 port?

Tags: thunderbolt, charging

I have a 2013 MacBook Air that is not charging. I suspect that the problem is the MagSafe port (or, more likely, the I/O board). An [iFixit Answer](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/224066/DC+IN+Voltage+Fails+TechToolPro+Diagnostic#answer501195) implies that it is possible to charge it using the Thunderbolt port. Is this true? And if so, what cables would I need to actually be able to plug it in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I charge my Macbook pro 2015 without using MagSafe 2 power port?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321797/can-i-charge-my-macbook-pro-2015-without-using-magsafe-2-power-port)

Comment: The difference is that this is a Thunderbolt 1 port, not a Thunderbolt 2 port—though it probably doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Thunderbolt ports cannot be used to charge pre-USB-C MacBooks.

If this were possible, the Apple Thunderbolt Display would surely have shipped with only a single Thunderbolt cable rather than its Thunderbolt + MagSafe hydra:

[image: Thunderbolt Display Connectors]